build goland Dockerfile, out put ERROR [3/9] COPY go.mod /app/go.mod
my Dockerfile detail is:
# Use the official Go image as the base image
FROM golang:1.22.0

# Set destination for COPY
WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod /app/go.mod
COPY go.sum /app/go.sum
# Download Go modules
RUN go mod download

COPY ./.env /app/.env
COPY ./config/config.json /app/config.json

COPY ./src/* /app

# Build the Go application
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o app

EXPOSE 8080
# Set the entry point for the container
CMD ["/app"]

When I run
docker build - < DockerFile

output
=> ERROR [3/9] COPY go.mod /app/go.mod                                                               0.0s
=> ERROR [4/9] COPY go.sum /app/go.sum                                                               0.0s
=> CACHED [5/9] RUN go mod download                                                                  0.0s
=> ERROR [6/9] COPY ./.env /app/.env                                                                 0.0s
=> ERROR [7/9] COPY ./config/config.json /app/config.json                                            0.0s
[3/9] COPY go.mod /app/go.mod:
[4/9] COPY go.sum /app/go.sum:
[6/9] COPY ./.env /app/.env:


[7/9] COPY ./config/config.json /app/config.json:
failed to compute cache key: "/.env" not found: not found
I have go.mod and go.sum file in my directory.


That unusual docker build syntax sends Docker the Dockerfile and nothing else, so COPY doesn't work.  You probably want docker build ..

docker: failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found is one of a couple of other questions that mention this, with fewer speculation around other problems.

find answer from docker build official doc
enter link description here
docker build - < Dockerfile


This example reads a Dockerfile from STDIN without context. Due to the lack of a context, the command doesn't send contents of any local directory to the Docker daemon. Since there is no context, a Dockerfile ADD only works if it refers to a remote URL.

